# Different behaviour when spring is used with junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I use spring 5 and I see, that spring behaves differently when I use it for tests (with junit 5) and in main code. The main thing, that singleton are not initialized during startup when I use spring for tests.

For example, this is my code

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class Foo<T> {

    public Foo(Class<T> someClass) {
         //...
    }
}
```

As it is seen, this class requires argument in constructor, so the instance of it I create manually - `context.getBean(....)`. When this class is used in tests - everything is ok. However, when I use it in main code I get at spring startup:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

This is the example of my test:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextConfig.class)
public class TestIT {}
```

How to explain such different behavior? I don't have much experience in spring, so would be thankful for any help.

Comment: The default scope in spring is singleton !

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchBeanDefinitionException means that Spring is not able to find the required bean in ApplicationContext. Based on your @Component class Foo, you have these options:

- Create a bean of Type Class, so that Spring can find it.
- Remove the constructor of Foo and set parameter someClass later with a setter method.
- Create a constructor without arguments and instanciate someClass inside the constructor.

Without knowing details about someClass, I am not able to say, what is the best option.

In my German blog, there is an article about Spring Basics: Beans & Dependency Injection, this explains the theory of what you try to do:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/kernkonzepte-von-spring-beans-und.html

PS.: Singleton is default scope of every Spring Bean, you can remove your @Scope annotation.